# SQL repeating long formula in a select clause

Tags: mysql, sql

In

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,since,until) dif,
       DATE_ADD(since,INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,since,until)/2 SECOND)
FROM....
```

That TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) is repeated through the select. Is there a way to simplify/reuse without repeating the whole formula? The alias "dif" is not valid in the SELECT arguments

Comment: You can use in-line variable assignment.

Comment: I like to repeat the whole formula. It might be slower to write, but it's often quicker to execute

Answer (score 3):

You can use SELECT to use the alias in the query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,since,until) dif,
       DATE_ADD(since,INTERVAL (SELECT dif)/2 SECOND)
FROM....
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to subquery whenever I have a cumbersome calculation in the select:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(since, INTERVAL dif/2 SECOND) FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,since,until) dif
    FROM....
) AS A
```

As a note, @clinomaniac answer is great for MySQL but is not recognized by all RDBMSs.

Comment: I marked accepted clinomaniac's answer because it seemed to me more graspable but digging into the subqueries I see a whole new spectrum of possibilities that may simplify queries even better...

Comment: Inline select and use of variable assignments both feel likes hacks to me, this would be the way I'd do it in ANSI-92 SQL in MySQL *(Until MySQL gets CTEs, etc, in version 8.)*